# Getting generic object field as array

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object which I want to use its array property called `serviceElements` inside the `GenericComponent`.

**Objects**

```
interface MyObject {
    id: number;
    serviceElements: ServiceElement[];
}

interface ServiceElement {
    id: number;
}
```

**GenericComponent**

```
interface Props<Type> {
    service: GenericService<Type>;
}

export default class GenericComponent<Type> extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    ....

    private fillDataTable = (): void => {

        service.list().then((data: Type[]) => {

            data.forEach(record => {

                // 1st attempt
                const array: ServiceElement[] = record['serviceElements'];

                // record['serviceElements'] gives the error:
                /* TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"serviceElements"' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
                    Property 'serviceElements' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
                */

                //////////////

                // 2th attempt
                const array: ServiceElement[] = record['serviceElements' as keyof Type];

                // const array gives the error:
                /* TS2322: Type 'Type[keyof Type]' is not assignable to type 'ServiceElement[]'.
                     Type 'Type[string] | Type[number] | Type[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'ServiceElement[]'.
                       Type 'Type[string]' is not assignable to type 'ServiceElement[]'.
                */
            }

        }

    }

    ....

}
```

Inside in a page the `GenericComponent` will be used like this:

```
<GenericComponent<MyObject> service={new MyObjectService()}/>
```

So, how can I get inside `GenericComponent` the `record`'s field `serviceElements` as array to loop on it?

I've added the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-ritchie-kfvs0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: We probably can't help you based on just the information above, we need more details. But you **may** want `const array = record.serviceElements;`. There's no need for brackets notation, and TypeScript will infer the type of `array` from the type of `record.serviceElements`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've just edited the question. Sorry, I just didn't want to make it more complex by sending all the unnecessary code. I think this would be enough?

Comment: What's the definition of `Type`? Your code is expecting `Type` to have string index access and/or a `serviceElements` property. If just `record.serviceElements` isn't working, then `Type` doesn't have that type.

Comment: I notice you're doing a lot of explicit typing of things, for instance the `data` parameter on the `then` handler on the promise that `service.list()` returns. If `service.list` is property defined, you shouldn't need to do that, and doing it makes maintenance more difficult.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The defenition of the `Type` is in this case `MyObject` becuase I call it `<GenericComponent<MyObject>../>`. And I'm very sure that `MyObject` has the `serviceElements` as you see above. I think typescript compiler just doesn't allow `any` type. I've also changed `service.list().then((data: Type[])` to `service.list().then(data` and indeed, doesn't need for that;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've just added codesandbox as you can find the link above. And I've realise that the `strict` option in the `tsconfig.json` can make these errors gone but this is something I am not allowed to remove. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you probably need `.map()`

```
data.map(m => m.serviceElements)
    .forEach(se => {
        // TODO: THINGS
    });
```

Comment: `m.serviceElements` gives the error: `TS2339: Property 'serviceElements' does not exist on type 'Type'.`